# How do I install tables module to run?

Tags: python, python-2.x

I am trying to run some code written by a collaborator in Python 2 which requires the tables module. I have checked that tables is installed by importing it successfully in a Python 3 shell at the command line but when I do the same for Python 2, there is no module named tables.

All answers I have found so far don't seem to solve my issue, any ideas?

Cheers :)

Comment: If you're talking about [PyTables](https://pypi.org/project/tables/), then you should look for an alternative as it only supports Python version >= 3.5.

Comment: Given that Python 2 is deprecated and will no longer be maintained in less than two months, the real solution is to stop using Python 2 immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Try download the package with

`pip install tables==3.5.2`  -- Python 2

Also, follow this issue on GitHub regarding this at [#772](https://github.com/PyTables/PyTables/issues/772)

> It's not recommended to use python2 as the end of its life on `January
>   1st, 2020`, Please consider visiting this documentation [Migrating
>   from PyTables 2.x to 3.x](http://www.pytables.org/MIGRATING_TO_3.x.html)

Comment: This only works if `pip` refers to `pip2`, which it may not do on all systems.

Comment: But you can always create an python2 environment and run this at it should work perfectly.But its not recommended as the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. @Adam you need to consider upgrading to python3

Answer (score 0):

Use Command - pip install tables

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip.exe install tables

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Collecting tables
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/86/34604cfd8e79d23ffef7f1c0ab134ddb98da572d0fcb9cb4631d5b47f549/tables-3.5.2-cp27-cp27m-win_amd64.whl (3.5MB)
     |UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU| 3.5MB 787kB/s
Collecting numexpr>=2.6.2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/45/d3/5997f8c7d48d4947665c7e7dfaabc3076da85390faf015288e39f242d520/numexpr-2.7.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl (106kB)
     |UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU| 112kB 3.4MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9.0 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from tables) (1.12.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.9.3 in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from tables) (1.16.5)
Collecting mock>=2.0
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/05/d2/f94e68be6b17f46d2c353564da56e6fb89ef09faeeff3313a046cb810ca9/mock-3.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting funcsigs>=1; python_version < "3.3"
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/69/cb/f5be453359271714c01b9bd06126eaf2e368f1fddfff30818754b5ac2328/funcsigs-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: numexpr, funcsigs, mock, tables
  WARNING: The scripts pt2to3.exe, ptdump.exe, ptrepack.exe and pttree.exe are installed in 'c:\python27\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed funcsigs-1.0.2 mock-3.0.5 numexpr-2.7.0 tables-3.5.2

C:\Python27\Scripts>
```